# Cordova app, authenticate WebView with native login

Tags: android, cordova, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Cordova application that I have built in Visual Studio 2015.  Basically all this app does is host a webview of the URL of my main website which is built in MVC4 (it uses bootstrap so looks very much like an app on a mobile device).

What I am looking to do is explore methods of building a native login screen before loading my webview, this will accept a PIN code for quick access to their account.

Is there any way to persist authentication by logging them in with WebAPI and then feeding this session into the webview?